# Joining SQL statements Atrium Syntess Firebird DB

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5

I'm trying to get (one or multiple) number lines (PROGCODE) that are attached to an OBJECT (i.e. a building) that is connected to a Relation which in turn has a GC_ID (relation unique ID). I need all the buildings & progcodes connected to a relation ID in a firebird 2.5 database generated by my companies ERP system.

I can look through all the tables in the firebird database and run select queries on them.I like to think I have the join statement syntax down and I know how to find the unique ID belonging to a relation, unfortunately I'm unsure how I can find the correct table that houses the information I seek.

The table I *think* this data is in has the following fields:

```
GC_ID, DEVICE_GC_ID, USER_GC_ID, CODE, DESCRIPTION.
```

However when I query it using

```
select GC_ID, DEVICE_GC_ID, USER_GC_ID, CODE, DESCRIPTION 
from AT_PROGCODE A
```

Then I get a description of the fields I'm trying to query.

i.e.

```
| GC_ ID : 100005 | DEVICE_GC_ID : 100174 | USER_GC_ID : 1000073 | DESCRIPTION: >description of what I'm trying to query< |
```

Can anyone shed some insight how I should handle this?

---

Update 7-09-2017

I spoke with the ERP consultant and was told the tables I needed (if anyone reading this is using syntess Atrium; the AT_BRENT table holds a description of all the tables.)

However, I've run into a new problem; the data I get from my sql query keeps streaming (it seems to never end with me stopping the script at 90 mil loops and the ERP program crashing if I ask for a count).

```
 select A.GC_OMSCHRIJVING Bedrijf, A.GC_CODE ,M.GC_OMSCHRIJVING Werktitel,  
        M.TELEFOON1, M.TELEFOON2, M.MOBIEL, M.EMAIL, 
        M.URL, M.DOORKIES_NR, M.WERKLOCATIE, M.EMAIL_INTERN 
from    AT_MEDEW M , AT_RELATIE A
JOIN    AT_MEDEW ON A.GC_ID = M.GC_ID
WHERE   M.TELEFOON1 <> '' OR  M.TELEFOON2 <> '' OR M.MOBIEL <> ''
```

Any ideas on what's the cause for my latest peril?

Comment: Looks to me like that is the data you are querying, in other words: the result of your query. Maybe I don't understand the question. Could you add the definition of the tables and a sample of data and expected results. Also, your query doesn't contain joins, so what more is missing from your question?

Comment: Does the said `OBJECT` has some unique human readable information, like unique textual name? One possible way would be to `extract` all the database to huge SQL script text file. Then to search that name in the file.

Comment: @Arioch'The , I doubt the code itself would show up in any other place than that so this si a possibility, I've already hooked up a python script to the .fdb file . What sort of sql query would I have to run to get all the values? In the ERP system it always requires a from component in the query

Comment: @MarkRotteveel It seems I forgot to add the join statement itself, however it looks exactly like the finale xample only that it uses the gc_ID's from actual customers.

Comment: I still don't understand your problem. Your query is asking for ids, Firebird returns those ids. What did you expect?

Comment: @Zr.Ms.Bruinvis I did not say "run SQL query" - I said "export all the database to text file of SQL language format". And I did not meant numeric codes, but unique textual names like "London" or "Berlin"

Comment: @MarkRotteveel My question is how I find sql query required to get _all the buildings & progcodes connected to a relation ID_ .. I thought I had the right table but I'm beginning to doubt that now.

Comment: @Arioch'The my apologies, I read your answer as 'EXPORT' being an SQL command. Unfortunately all the progcodes are numerical, but I reckon if I could query all the tables that I'd be able to find the table I need.

Comment: I think you really need to contact the vendor of your application. Firebird is a generic database management system, your question seems to be about the specifics of the schema of your application (which uses Firebird). Without knowledge of that schema and the application that is hard (if not impossible) to answer (or would come down to guess work).

Comment: all progcodes may be numerical, but the objects may (or may not) have not only progcodes but some other unique textual attributes that you can search through.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I tried contacting the vendor, they said all information was viewable through a database viewer inside the ERP..  there I can see tables, views,procedures,triggers,generators and Indices objects. But this hasn't helped me find the specific data I seek

Comment: That is unfortunate, but as I said, without knowledge of this specific schema, it will be next to impossible to help you. And if your vendor can't or doesn't want to help, you are on your own. I can only suggest you study the schema and see if you can infer any logic about its structure, and then test your assumptions by creating queries and comparing them to results in the application itself. You could also try to use the Firebird trace facility and check what kind of queries the application itself generates and see if that gives you hints about the structure.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel he can also try to trace all the real queries going in, like implementing his own FB client library as proxy with logging, or perhaps using FB 2.5 trace api ( like https://ib-aid.com/en/hqbird-features ). Then he can try to keep his system idle for few minutes, then open needed data, and when it is loaded - stop tracing and see which queries got issued in that very minute. Problem: ERP lego would probably tend to make all tables data joins inside the client application, with only indirect hints at it in the queries themselves.

Comment: @Arioch'The you can see it running the sql queries, but obviously the company didn't want to share those queries (or it's above the need-to-know paygrade of a service desk employee) Eitgher way an advisor is coming by monday (for an unrelated issue) .. i'll try to sneak in  a few questiosn about this subject then.

Comment: I meant exactly seeing the queries run by application. But by nature of ERP and ORM systems (heavy caching, data links coded in the ERP itself and removed from SQL layer) they would probably be of limited help

Comment: I spoke to the consultant and updated my question , I atleast get the data to show now.. but it doesnt seem to end.. I am however not entirely sure if the fault is on my end. As the data I do get is the information I seek

Comment: Your query from the ERP guy has a CROSS JOIN in it.  That's why you're getting a huge number of results.  I think you're going to need to start by learning SQL and understanding how JOINs work.  That's really basic stuff, and you don't seem to know it.  Unfortunately, you need to have that understanding to be able to do anything.  Since we're not in a position to understand the DB schema or what you want returned, it's going to be difficult for us to even understand what your query is trying to do.

Comment: I'm trying to get the fields that I linked,  A.GC_OMSCHRIJVING , A.GC_CODE ,  GC_ID (shared key)  are in the table 1:  'AT_RELATIE' ,     M.GC_ID (shared key) , M.TELEFOON1, M.TELEFOON2, M.MOBIEL, M.EMAIL, 
        M.URL, M.DOORKIES_NR, M.WERKLOCATIE, M.EMAIL_INTERN  are in table 2  'AT_MEDEW'    ... I wont claim to be a database engineer anytime soon, but I like to think I'm learning, like now I know what a CROSS JOIN is. Thanks for your help bacon

Answer (score 0):

First I had to find the AT_BRENT table which holds all the descriptions for tables in Syntess Atrium

Then I was using a CROSS JOIN (as pointed out by https://stackoverflow.com/users/696808/bacon-bits )

I ended up using

```
    select A.GC_OMSCHRIJVING Bedrijf, A.GC_CODE ,M.GC_OMSCHRIJVING Werktitel,  
    M.TELEFOON1, M.TELEFOON2, M.MOBIEL, M.EMAIL, 
    M.URL, M.DOORKIES_NR, M.WERKLOCATIE, M.EMAIL_INTERN 
    from    AT_MEDEW M
    JOIN  AT_RELATIE A ON A.GC_ID = M.GC_ID
    WHERE   M.TELEFOON1 <> '' OR  M.TELEFOON2 <> '' OR M.MOBIEL <> ''
```

Thank you all who helped.

Comment: The problem with your query from yesterdays edit was that you combined SQL-89 implicit joins with SQL-92 explicit joins, and your explicit join condition did not actually reference that table (which transformed the inner join to a cross join). However I was not the one to point it out; that was https://stackoverflow.com/users/696808/bacon-bits instead

Comment: You're right once mork @MarkRotteveel - I'm on a roll here! I edited the answer; thanks again for your time and expertise attention.